# TypeError: Cannot read property 'createAllDayEvent' of null when creating GoogleScripts automation

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, calendar

First of all, I am a very new programmer, so I apologize for my ignorance. Regardless, I wrote this code today to take data from a google sheet, and import that to a google calendar.

```
//create deposit date 
function sheetsToCalendar() {
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("[omitted]@group.calendar.google.com");
  var lastRow = spreadsheet.getLastRow();

  var depositDate = spreadsheet.getRange(lastRow, 28).getValue(); 

  Logger.log(depositDate)
  eventCal.createAllDayEvent('Deposit Date', depositDate)

}
```

The intention being that anytime the program is executed,that the last cell of column 28 is the date being added to the google calendar.

However, when it is run, I get the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'createAllDayEvent' of null`.

The `Logger.log(depositDate)` produces the correct date assigned in the spreadsheet, so I am not sure where to look.

Thank you again :)

Comment: Looks like the script failed to get access to the calendar. Try put the line: `console.log(eventCal.getName())` right before `var lastRow = ...`. It should show the name of the calendar. If it doesn't, you need to look at the ID of the calendar more closely, probably error is there. Just a guess.

Comment: > Calendar — the calendar with the given ID, or null if the calendar does not exist, if the user cannot access it, or if the user is not subscribed to the calendar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
function sheetsToCalendar() {
  const sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(gobj.globals.calendarid);//contains a global object parameter that holds my calendar id
  const depositDate = new Date(sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow(), 28).getValue());//try using the new Date() constructor to get the date from a spreadsheet
  Logger.log(depositDate)
  cal.createAllDayEvent('Deposit Date', depositDate);//this was created on my calendar
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that you can't put a ID from a different account that you using in your App Script's project in the getCalendarById function.

For example, if you are editing your script in the "nicolas@gmail.com" you need to create an calendar ID using the same email account.

This fixed the null error for me.